# scala.MatchError: String Extraction using regular expression

Tags: scala

I am working on scala pattern matching.

For the below program I am getting output.

```
   val pattern = "([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z]+)".r

   val pattern(count,fruit) ="100 bananas"
```

The output of the program is

count: String = 100
fruit: String = bananas

I modified the program to get deeper understanding, by adding one more numeric pattern into the pattern val object and one more object into the extraction pattern val.

The program is

```
  val pattern = "([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z]+)  ([0-9]+) ".r

  val pattern(count, fruit, price) ="100 bananas 1002"
```

But the program is not compiling and it is throwing error. The error is -

```
scala.MatchError: 100 bananas 1002 (of class java.lang.String)
at #worksheet#.x$1$lzycompute(ExtractingStrings.sc0.tmp:6)
at #worksheet#.x$1(ExtractingStrings.sc0.tmp:6)
at #worksheet#.count$lzycompute(ExtractingStrings.sc0.tmp:6)
at #worksheet#.count(ExtractingStrings.sc0.tmp:6)
at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(ExtractingStrings.sc0.tmp:6)
```

Can anyone explain why it is throwing this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program is compiling just fine. What you are getting is a runtime exception ([scala.MatchError](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.MatchError)).

This is because your second pattern `"([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z]+)  ([0-9]+) "` has 2 spaces after `([A-Za-z]+)` and an additional space at the end after `([0-9]+)` and `100 bananas 1002` does not match that patter (one space after `bananas` and no space after `1002`).

Remove those spaces, change the pattern into `([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z]+) ([0-9]+)"` and it will work.

```
scala> val pattern = "([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z]+) ([0-9]+)".r
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = ([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z]+) ([0-9]+)

scala> val pattern(count, fruit, price) ="100 bananas 1002"
count: String = 100
fruit: String = bananas
price: String = 1002
```

Comment: I have changed the pattern as you have suggested. It is not working.

Comment: val pattern = "([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z]+) ([0-9]+)".r

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan no problem, if you have any other doubts please edit your question. Otherwise please accept this answer so other people know this question was already solved.

Comment: Accepted your answer. Thanks a lot.